# How to Run a Single Line in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am used to using the standard R GUI but I'm trying to make the switch to RStudio. However, it's driving me nuts that I can't figure out how to run a single line with a keyboard shortcut. For instance, if I have the two lines,

```
c <- a +
     b
```

I would like to press ^R to run the first line and then have to press ^R *again* to run the second line to complete the assignment. This is the default setting in the standard R GUI. Unfortunately, RStudio only seems to want to execute a statement to it's completion. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Would be helpful to have your RStudio version as only executing a single line is the norm in my 0.98 version (Windows).

Comment: That's interesting. I wish that were the norm for me. But I'm running 3.4.2 on Linux.

Comment: 3.4.2 is your R version, not your RStudio version. The highest stable version of RStudio is 1.0.153.

Comment: Ah thanks for the clarification. My newness to RStudio is showing. I am using 1.0.153.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this to be the default behavior, go to "Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Editing" and uncheck the box "Execute all lines in a statement" under "Execution".

Comment: That worked. I was too focused on troubleshooting through the Keyboard Shortcuts options.

Answer (score 2):

Select the first line (by clicking on it three times), then Ctrl-Enter will run the selection, not the statement.

Comment: So far that's the only workaround I've been able to come up with. But having to highlight each line as I go diminishes the value of line-by-line execution imo. Is this the only option?

Comment: This seems like something you'd rarely need.  Normally I want the Ctrl-Enter behaviour, because it really saves keystrokes:  e.g. put the cursor on the first line of a function definition, then Ctrl-Enter runs the whole thing.  The RGui behaviour feels a lot less efficient:  you only need that when you want to input part of a statement, then type some change.  So highlighting the part you want makes sense.

Comment: I agree, it's utility is limited. The value I get from it is hard to describe and may be unique to my programming style.